Tap on the StackView elements nothing happens in simulator
I encountered a problem, it doesn't work. When I assign a tap to a StackView element and tap through the simulator, nothing happens. Please tell me in detail what the problem is, what I misunderstand.
I created UITableView which contains CustomCell. CustomCell contains ViewWrap and ViewWrap contains StackView with View as elements. I assign a UITapGestureRecognizer to a View that contains a StackView.
P.S. In the future, I will change the code and create two user classes (there will be different functions for taps) for all views that are included in StackView.
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let ident = "cell"

    let viewWrapp: UIView = {
       let vwWrapp = UIView()
       vwWrapp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return vwWrapp
    }()
    
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
       var st = UIStackView()
       st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       st.axis = .horizontal
       st.distribution = .fillEqually
       st.alignment = .bottom
       st.spacing = 0
       st.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
       return st
    }()
    
    var view11: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.text = "4"
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 47)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        
        vw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: CustomCell.self, action: #selector(tabTab))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        vw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return vw
    }()
        
    var view22: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.text = "+"
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 30)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        vw.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        vw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: CustomCell.self, action: #selector(tabTab))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        vw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return vw
    }()
    
// ...   ...
// ...   ...
// ...   ...

    var view77: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.text = "4"
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 47)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        vw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: CustomCell.self, action: #selector(tabTab))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        vw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return vw
    }()
    
    var view88: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.text = "="
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 30)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        
        return vw
    }()
    
    var view99: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 47)

        vw.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        vw.numberOfLines = 0
        return vw
    }()
    
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        contentView.addSubview(viewWrapp)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view11)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view22)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view33)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view44)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view55)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view66)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view77)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view88)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view99)
        
        viewWrapp.addSubview(stackView)
        
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    @objc func tabTab(){
        print("Tab Tab")
    }
    
    func setConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            viewWrapp.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            viewWrapp.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            viewWrapp.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWrapp.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWrapp.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
        ])
    }
}

I tried to assign a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view that is in the StackView, but there was no response to the tap. Also added isUserInteractionEnabled = true in:

View what in StackView
StackView
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle
override func awakeFromNib()
tabView.delaysContentTouches = false


In all of your tap gestures, change CustomCell.self to just self.

BTW - it would be so much simpler to use a UIButton instead of a UILabel. Then you don't need any tap gestures.

To summarise your problem,
you are trying to add a tap gesture in a view (in your case it's a UILabel) but it's not working.
There is a similar problem which you can check How to set a click event on a UIStackview
To solve your problem, one of the many solutions is to make all of the
UILabel var to lazy var and modify UITapGestureRecognizer target parameter CustomCell.self to self.
Apart from the solution,
You have added translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to every child UILabel which is not required since you are setting NSLayoutConstraint only in viewWrapp and stackView.
I have added a working solution from your provided code snippet.
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let ident = "cell"
    
    lazy var viewWrapp: UIView = {
        let vwWrapp = UIView()
        vwWrapp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return vwWrapp
    }()
    
    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        var st = UIStackView()
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        st.axis = .horizontal
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.alignment = .bottom
        st.spacing = 0
        st.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
        return st
    }()
    
    lazy var view11: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.text = "4"
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 47)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        
        vw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tabTab))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        vw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return vw
    }()
    
    lazy var view22: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.text = "+"
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 30)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        vw.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        vw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tabTab))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        vw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return vw
    }()
    
    lazy var view77: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.text = "4"
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 47)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        vw.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tabTab))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        vw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return vw
    }()
    
    lazy var view88: UILabel = {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.text = "="
        vw.font = UIFont(name: "LittleBird", size: 30)
        vw.textAlignment = .center
        
        return vw
    }()
    
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view11)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view22)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view77)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view88)
        
        
        contentView.addSubview(viewWrapp)
        viewWrapp.addSubview(stackView)
        
        setConstraints()
        
    }
    
    func setConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            viewWrapp.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            viewWrapp.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            viewWrapp.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWrapp.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWrapp.bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWrapp.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWrapp.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func tabTab(){
        print("Tab Tab")
    }
}

Apart from my solution, this problem can solved in many ways.
For example: Adding buttons mentioned by @HangarRash comments.

Adding lazy doesn't change the result at all.

The question you linked has nothing to do with this question. This OP is not trying to add a tap gesture to a UIStackView.

@HangarRash have you tested my sample code? Before I posted, I have tested this solution in Xcode 15.3 :(

I didn't say your solution doesn't work (I didn't try it). But your answer states the solution is to add lazy. But adding lazy doesn't change anything in this case. If your answer works then most likely it is because you also changed the target parameter to self for all of the tap gestures (as I mentioned in my comment below the question). Your answer makes no mention of that important change.

@HangarRash without adding lazy, add the target parameter to self which doesn't work. The link I suggested, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/78392494/6634614

@HangarRash Thanks for mentioning that. I am editing the solution.

Oh right, I forget it needs to be lazy to reference self. But still, the key point of your answer is the change of target for the tap gesture. Adding lazy is just a byproduct of using self. lazy is not the solution in of itself.

@Md Abul Kashem thank you very much for the detailed, informative answer and clarification of the mention of laziness and definitely understood me and my question) I read and looked for information on the Internet, but it doesn’t seem to have paid enough attention to the target. It looks like I didn’t 100% understand the information.
Can you explain how to correctly understand what needs to be used in the target?

@HangarRash Thank you very much for the quick response)
You're right, using buttons would probably be a more attractive solution. I asked a similar question in my local forum chat, but didn’t receive any acceptable answer and decided to simply select the label. Apparently I didn’t properly understand the question with the target, in what cases and what to choose and what needs to be submitted to the target.
Could you give me some advice on how to work with Target?

@VladislavZhelezniak, by target I meant to change
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: CustomCell.self, action: #selector(tabTab)) target value  to let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tabTab)) which is used to set tap gesture inside your label. In your case  var view77: UILabel

@VladislavZhelezniak You can up-vote any answer if it works. Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269683/6634614 how to say thanks in StackOverflow?

@Md Abul Kashem Grateful for your answer. I realized that I made a mistake when I passed the target CustomCell.self instead of self. That's what offered by the XCode. I will study the target parameter)
